# LSTM **kwargs understanding python

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm, keyword-argument

I made a LSTM based model for disease forecasting a few months back and I am now writing my work. I used Functional API. I followed a tutorial but they didn't mentioned about it. I understand most of LSTM parameters but failed to understand the following:

```
lstm_kwargs = {'dropout': 0.20, 'recurrent_dropout': 0.1, 'return_sequences': True, 'implementation': 2}
lstm1 = LSTM(200, name='lstm1', **lstm_kwargs)(input_layer)
```

The only problem is the `'implementation': 2`. What does implementation means here?

Regards.

Comment: Which version of Keras is this? There is no implementation parameter in LSTM according to the documentation

Comment: I don't remember. It was from a Nvidia course. `Modeling Time Series Data with Recurrent Neural Networks in Keras`

Comment: https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/v2.9.0/keras/layers/rnn/lstm.py#L167-L172